# Ilegal format conversion issue

Tags: java

I can get an output from the second print out - 17.83 but i keep getting IllegalFormatConversionException when I try to use the first system out print sentence.

```
import java.util.Formatter;
public class Q1
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        double r = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double a = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

        double area = 0.5*(Math.pow(r, 2))*(((a*(22/7))/180)- Math.sin((a*(22/7))/180));
        System.out.format("Area is %.2f", area + " when radius is " + r + " and angle is " + a); 
        System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
```

Comment: Well, the string `area + " when radius is " + r + " and angle is " + a`is not a floating number. So you can't format it with %.2f.

Comment: ALWAYS post the complete error message when asking about errors. Don't paraphrase it as you will likely leave out important information that the message contains. Your format String should contain all the concrete String elements, and yours doesn't.

Comment: Change to `System.out.format("Area is %.2f when radius is %.2f and angle is %.2f", area, r, a);` and read the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 2):

Your format String should contain all the concrete String elements, and yours doesn't. So not

```
System.out.format("Area is %.2f", area + " when radius is " + r + " and angle is " + a);
```

but rather

```
System.out.format("Area is %.2f when radius is %.2f and angle is %.2f", area, r, a);
```

In the future, ALWAYS post the complete error message when asking about errors. Don't paraphrase it as you will likely leave out important information that the message contains

Answer (score -1):

This

```
System.out.format("Area is %.2f", area + " when radius is " + r + " and angle is " + a);
```

should be (in order to compile)

```
System.out.format("Area is %.2f when radius is " + r + " and angle is " + a, area);
```

and in order to look nice:

```
System.out.format("Area is %.2f when radius is %.2f and angle is %.2f",  area, r, a);
```

In your version you are passing `"Area is %.2f"` as the first argument and something like `"6.28244564556 when radius is 1.0 and angle is 6.28244564556"`. (the numbers will be different). The second argument obviously can't be parsed as a float. Hence the error.